# I have problem in listing (ls command ) file when make shared folder in vmware

Tags: 22.04, vmware, shared-folders, ls

I wanted to make a shared folder with this [tutorial](https://alexandrerosseto.medium.com/vmware-linux-how-to-share-folder-between-host-and-vm-62e63419ecbb#:%7E:text=STEP-BY-STEP&text=Go%20to%20VM%20menu%2C%20after,local%20folder%20to%20share%20it.&text=In%20order%20to%20confirm%20if,your%20folder%20will%20be%20listed.) from medium. but after doing that and when I wanted to check for the files I shared, this just happened
[ls command output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSvql.png)
simultaneously folder "shared" is created and not available !

Do anybody know what is the problem?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the elements of the solution you've tried in the post itself rather than relying on a link to the guide you followed. We need to understand what steps you took specifically and the error messages you got in the process as they will help us better diagnose your problem.